# QT how to save to file QPoint 2d array

Tags: c++, qt

I have board where I can "draw" a number.

[image]

This is code of board

```
void PrintRectangle::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
{
 for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        ypos=20;
        for(int j=0; j<5; j++)
        {
            QColor color = Qt::white;
            for(int k=0; k<points.size(); k++){

                  if( i == points[k].x() && j == points[k].y() )
                  {
                     color = Qt::black;
                  }

            }
            p.fillRect(xpos,ypos,recWidth,recHeight,color);
            ypos+=60;
        }
        xpos+=60;
    }
}
```

And next function, which updated points on list

```
 QVector<QPoint> points;
    void PrintRectangle::updateIndexFromPoint(const QPoint &point)
    {
        int x = point.x() - 20;
        int y = point.y() - 20;
        bool removed = false;

        if( ( (x >= 0 )  && ( x <= 300) ) && ( (y >= 0 )  && ( y <= 300) ) )
        {
            mXIndex = x / 60; //rec width + spacing
            mYIndex = y / 60; //rec height + spacing

            for(int k=0; k<points.size(); k++){

                qDebug("%d %d", points[k].x(), points[k].y());

                if(points[k].x() == mXIndex && points[k].y() == mYIndex){

                    points.remove(k);
                    removed = true;
                }

            }

            if(!removed){
               points.append(QPoint(mXIndex,mYIndex));
            }
        } 
    }
```

My question is how can I save to file numer from QPoint selected rectangle.

eg. numer 1 in file

```
0 0 1 0 0
0 1 1 0 0
1 0 1 0 0
0 0 1 0 0
0 0 1 0 0
```

Comment: `std::fstream`?

Comment: I but how to recognize `0` and `1`, iterate of `QPoint`?

Comment: you can draw it, of course you know which is `0` and `1`, aren't you?

Comment: Formally yes, I should iterate of QPoint with two for loop as in `paintEvent` and put numer to file yes?

Comment: yes, another way is initialize a 2D array (contains `0`) and set `1`'s in it, then save the array (it is easy now)

Comment: Initialize using `memset`?

Comment: `bool field[5][5]={}` is enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use [QDataStream](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatastream.html) to store your points in file:

```
void savePoints(QVector<QPoint> points)
{
    QFile file("points.bin");
    if(file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly))
    {
        QDataStream out(&file);
        out.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_4_0);
        out << points;
        file.close();
    }
}

QVector<QPoint> loadPoints()
{
    QVector<QPoint> points;
    QFile file("points.bin");
    if(file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
    {
        QDataStream in(&file);
        in.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_4_0);
        in >> points;
        file.close();
    }
    return points;
}
```